# jquery error with check if blank form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small problem with jquery ... I have a form with default 2 fields, if one of the 2 is empty the send button turns off. It works

But I also add a "+" button that allows you to add text fields, it also works. But the control of these fields does not work, if there is nothing in the send button is still activate .

here is my code:

```
<table class="form-table" id="customFields">

    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName1">Question</label></th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" id="customFieldQuestion" name="customFieldName[]" value="test" placeholder="Question"/> &nbsp;
            <input type="text" class="" id="customFieldReponse" name="customFieldValue[]" value="test" placeholder="Reponse"/> &nbsp;

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Supprimer</a>
        </td>
        </div>

    </tr>

</table>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" id="addCF" >+</a>
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" form="formfaq" type="submit" id="go" name="go">
    Envoyer<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName1">Question</label></th><div class="input-field col s12"><td><input type="text" class="" id="customFieldQuestion" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Question"/> &nbsp;<input type="text" class="" id="customFieldReponse" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Reponse"/> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></div></tr>');
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#go').attr('disabled',false);

    $('[id="customFieldQuestion"]').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('#go').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('#go').attr('disabled',true);
    })

    $('[id="customFieldReponse"]').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('#go').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('#go').attr('disabled',true);
    })
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: First clean up your HTML. You can't have a `div` wrapping your `td`. Then change the `id`s, an id should be unique! First then we can help you with the rest...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    <form>
    <table class="form-table" id="customFields">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName1">Question</label></th>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="field_customFieldQuestion" id="customFieldQuestion" name="customFieldName[]" value="test" placeholder="Question"/> &nbsp;
                    <input type="text" class="field_customFieldReponse" id="customFieldReponse" name="customFieldValue[]" value="test" placeholder="Reponse"/> &nbsp;

                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Supprimer</a>
                </td>
            </div>

        </tr>

    </table>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" id="addCF" >+</a>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large" form="formfaq" type="submit" id="go" name="go">
        Envoyer<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addCF").click(function(){
            $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName1">Question</label></th><div class="input-field col s12"><td><input type="text" class="field_customFieldQuestion" id="customFieldQuestion" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Question"/> &nbsp;<input type="text" class="field_customFieldReponse" id="customFieldReponse" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Reponse"/> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></div></tr>');
            $('#go').attr('disabled',true);
        });
        $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            $(".field_customFieldReponse").trigger("change")
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var customQue = 0;
        var customRes = 0;
        $('#go').attr('disabled',false);
        $("#addCF").click(function(){
            customQue = 0;
            customRes = 0;
        })
        var requiredFields =  ['customFieldQuestion', 'customFieldReponse'];
        requiredFields.forEach(function(input) {
            $(document).on("keyup blur change click", ".field_" + input, function(e) {
                if(input == "customFieldQuestion"){
                    if($(this).val().trim() != ""){
                        customQue = 1;
                    }else{
                        customQue = 0;
                    }
                }else if(input = "customFieldReponse") {
                    if($(this).val().trim() != ""){
                        customRes = 1;
                    }else{
                        customRes = 0;
                    }
                }
                else{

                    }
                if(customQue == 1 && customRes == 1){
                    $('#go').attr('disabled', false);
                }else{
                    $('#go').attr('disabled',true);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't have multiple elements with the same id. Your html is not valid (you have multiple `#customFieldQuestion` and `#customFieldReponse`). You need to use something else like classes or [data-custom attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).
2. You can't set listener on dynamic content, you should set it on a static parent using [the delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like `$('#customFields').on('keyup', '[data-custom="customFieldQuestion"]', function(){ ...`

Comment: i try with data-custom properties but i have same problem

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can't assign listener to dynamic content too. I added some documentation links